# Securely store Hash in Docker Image

Tags: python-3.x, security, docker, encryption

I am building a series of applications using Docker and want to securely store my api keys, db access keys, etc. In an effort to make my application more secure, I am storing my configuration file in a password protected, zipped, volume set to read-only. I can use the `ZipFile` python package to access this to read in the configuration, including using a password.

However, I don't want to store the password explicitly in the image, for obvious reasons. I have played around with `passlib` to generate a hash for the password and compare. While I am fine with storing the hash in a file in the image, generating the hash I'd like to do without storing the value in a layer of the image.

Would it be good practice to do this? The `Dockerfile` I have in mind would look like the following:

```
FROM my_custom_python_image:3.6

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN python create_hash.py --token 'mysecret' >> myhash.txt

# The rest of the file here
```

And `create_hash.py` would look like:

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
import argparse

# Logic to get my argparse token flag 

hash = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(args.token, rounds=200000, salt_size=16)
print(hash)
```

If my `Dockerfile` is not stored in the image and the file system is read only, is the value I put to `--token` stored? If if is, what's a good workaround here? Again, the end goal is to use `context.verify(user_token, hash)` to pass the `user_token` to `ZipFile` and not explicitly store the password anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass these values as part of the run time deployment, not build time.

It makes your application more flexible (as it can be used in different environments with only parameter changes) and more secure as the keys are simply not there.

To pass values securely during deployment depends more on the deployed environment and features

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can tweak my code to run in this fashion. I'm using VSTS to run a CI/CD pipeline, so this should be feasible and allow me to keep the secrets from being viewable. I figured this would probably be the way to go, but just wanted to test the waters

Answer (score 1):

Anything in a `RUN` command will be later visible via `docker history`.

The most secure readily accessible way to provide configuration like passwords to an application like this is to put the configuration file in a host directory with appropriate permissions and then use `docker run -v` or a similar option to mount that into the running container.  Depending on how much you trust your host system, passing options as environment variables works well too (anyone who can run `docker inspect` or anyone else with root access on the system can see that, but they could read a config file too).

With your proposed approach, I suspect you will need the actual password (not a hash) to decrypt the file.  Also configuration by its nature changes somewhat independently of the application, which means you could be in a situation where you need to rebuild your application just because a database hostname changed, which isn't quite what you usually want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to avoid using environment variables because they are easy to extract and view. You are correct that I need the exact password to decrypt the file, but doing a hash comparison rather than an explicit string comparison reads more secure in my mind. Then I can pass the runtime-given token to the zipfile for read access